# Частое обновление приложения на андроид другим приложением

Tags: android, обновление

подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли такая возможность, как обновление приложения другим приложением в смартфоне xiaomi 9 андроид 11 Miui . 
У меня установлено приложение для курьера, чтоб видеть заказы новые, надо постоянно обновлять страничку оттягивая вниз, только так будут появляться/обновляться новые заказы. Проблем нет, когда заказов много , а когда глухая пора, то приходиться сидеть и постоянно обновлять. Это муторно и неудобно, за час может ничего не быть, а через час и 5 сек что-то появится, а ты "плюнул" и устав перестал обновлять 
Подскажите, есть ли какое-то приложение, которое будет обновлять или перезагружать страницу другого приложения или это с техническо-безопасной стороны почти невозможно?

Comment: Невозможно такое. Ну и вопрос не тематичен для StackOverflow. Такое лучше просить у авторов приложения. По идее, должен приходить пуш о заказе. Может у вас пуши выключены для этого приложения?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и прошу прощения у участников этого форума за мой пост, если не в тему. Здесь был подобный вопрос(нашёл через поиск) и подумал, что можно задать вопрос.

Comment: Тут вопросы по части именно разработки задают. Вам, вероятно, лучше вопрос или у авторов приложения спросить, или на 4PDA.

Comment: Если не оттягивать страницу вниз в приложении для обновления, то новые заказы не появятся. Если их нет, то и не будет, пока к примеру не перейдёшь на другую страницу(профиль и.п.) то по возвращению на "доступные" заказы, она(страница) обновляется и показывает наличие. А если никаких манипуляций не производить с приложение, то и обновления не будет .

Comment: Понял, спасибо за совет.